# Asp.Net MVC3 Razor submit calling method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**Hello, I'm new i mvc, I have next view**

```
@model MeterProfileData.Core.Dto.CdapiDto

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/SiteMaster.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add new CDAPI</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Url)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Url)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Url)
        </div>
      <p>
        <input type="submit"  value="Save" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "CdapiList")
</div>
```

**and next controler**

```
public class CdapiController : Controller
  {
    //
    // GET: /Cdapi/

    public ActionResult CdapiList()
    {
      var cdapiList = new CdapiService().GetListCdapiServers();
      return View(cdapiList);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
      return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CdapiDto dto)
    {
      new CdapiService().CreateCdapi(dto);
      return RedirectToAction("CdapiList");
    }
  }
```

After submit always call first method and page refreshed. What I'm doing wrong? and what to do for calling second method and send to it parameters from page

**Master Layout**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test mvc</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
    </link>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/javascript/jquery-1.7.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-jtemplates.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <h3>
                View Pages</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a runat="server" href="/Register">Registers</a></li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="/MeterProfile">Meter Profiles</a></li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="/register/SupportedRegisters">Supported Registers </a></li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="/logers/SupportedLogers">Supported Loggers </a></li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="/Cdapi/CdapiList">CDAPI Servers </a></li>
            </u>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure its not calling the second create and then redirecting to  theCdapiList ?

Answer (score 3):

You have another `form` tag in your Master Layout right after the opening `<body>` tag. Remove that form and you should be good then.

Comment: Yeh :(. I was copy master layout from Asp.Net project. And forgot about form there. Thanks Now all is works

Comment: No problem. I only know this from self experience :( If it resolved your issue, please check mark as answered.

Answer (score -1):

i'm not sure what you want to achieve, but you need to tell it which action to post to:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Cdapi", FormMethod.Post))
```

Comment: I try it. @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Cdapi", FormMethod.Post))  not help

Comment: are you saying that if you put a breakpoint on new CdapiService().CreateCdapi(dto) it doesn't stop?

Comment: The code you wrote is reduntant - it already works that way by default

Comment: @Razvan Yes. breakpoint stop only in Create() method not in Create(CdapiDto dto)

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another `form` wrapped around this one? In the browser look at the HTML and see if you can find one.

Comment: @Jisaak Yes I'm sure, I was add my master layout code in to the question. You can check